# Transport property

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

This question is prompted by Example 2.4.9 of the HoTT book. It is stated that, "for any $p:x =_A y$ and $P: A \to \mathcal{U}$ the function $\text{transport}^P(p,-): P(x) \to P(y)$ has a quasi-inverse given by $\text{transport}^P(p^{-1},-)$; this follows from Lemma 2.3.9.

Recall, $p_*$ and alternate notation for the transport function mentioned above. Consider the following as a check of the above claim. Let $u : P(x)$ and $v: P(y)$

$(p^{-1})_* \circ p_*(u) = (p \cdot p^{-1})_* (u) = (\text{refl}_x)_*(v) \equiv \text{id}_{P(x)}(v)$

where the first identification is justified by Lemma 2.3.9. Similarly

$p_* \circ (p^{-1})_*(v) = \text{id}_{P(y)}(v)$

I have not been able to justify the second identification, that is $(p \cdot p^{-1})(u) = (\text{refl}_x)_* (u)$. Of course, we know fom Lemma 2.1.4. that $p \cdot p^{-1} = \text{refl}_x$.

So this leads to my question:
Can we define a function of the following type (prove the propostion): given $p,q : x = y$ and $P : A \to \mathcal{U}$ and $u : P(x)$

$(p = q) \to p_*(u) = q_*(u)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in fact you can. You essentially want to inhabit, for any $x, y : A$ and $u : B(x)$, $\prod_{p,\ q : x = y} p = q \to  p_*(u)=q_*(u)$. By path induction, we may assume $q$ is $p$ and specify the image of refl in $p_*(u)=p_*(u)$. So we may choose $refl_{p_*(u)}$.

This come up later in the HoTT book, in the section on higher inductive types. You have to define this function, called transport$^2$, so that you can define 2 dimensional dependent paths.

But this function is not necessary to justify the fact that $p_*$ is an equivalence with quasi-inverse $p^{-1}_*$. You can show this just using lemmas regarding the transport function.

Let me walk through how to show that $p_*$ has quasi-inverse $p_*^{-1}$:

This is probably the easiest way: we want to inhabit $(p^{-1}_*\circ p_*)(u) = u$. By induction on $p$. We assume $p$ is $refl$, in which case we only need to inhabit $(refl_*\circ refl_*)(u) = u$, since $refl^{-1}\equiv refl$. But since $refl_*\equiv Id_{B(x)}$, we have $refl_*\circ refl_*(u) \equiv u$. So we may choose $refl_u$.

Here is a more direct way along the line of what you were thinking. First, $(p^{-1}_*\circ p_*)(u)=(p\cdot p^{-1})_*(u)$. As you mention, this follows from lemma 2.3.9. Now, how do we derive the next equality? We can use the action on path, $ap$, function on the function $(\lambda q . q_*(u)) : x = y \to B(y)$. So we have that  $ap(\lambda (q : x = x) . q_*(u))(ru) :(p\cdot p^{-1})_*(u) = refl_*(u)\equiv u$, where $ru:p\cdot p^{-1} = refl_x$.

Now that I think about it, it turns out that transport$^2(r)$=ap($\lambda(q).q_*(u))(r)$. So it turns out that either way is equivalent. Additionally, the first method which uses path induction is, I think, equivalent to these other two as well.

Comment: Which lemma do you have in mind to justify $(p \cdot p^{-1})_*(u) = (\text{refl}_x)_*(u)$?

Comment: Path induction?

Comment: @ToucanIan I just realized I totally misunderstood you! Let me edit my response!

Comment: No problem! Thanks!

Comment: @ToucanIan I updated the answer.

Comment: Really thankful for this insight. In the HoTT book it simply says that the result follows from lemma 2.3.9. I'm not sure I would have thought to use $\text{ap}_f$! I agree path induction is the easiest.